React Native with mmkv storage display items in the list
Looking for any tips, I am new to React Native after some research found that storing user data locally is better with MMKV package. Documentation shows basic queries based on constants, however what if you have a heap of elements and want to display them in a FlatList?
for example you have 100 items saved in storage:
storage.set(uuid(), `item ${n}`)


You need to persist these items? Don’t store them 1 by 1.

@johnhaup, can you elaborate? I am trying to save the state so it won't be erased after app is terminated and also display them in a flat list.
The only solution I came up with, is to persist values in mmkv store and keep them in useState array, so I could display them in a Flat List
